# Adding two numbers represented as linked lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, linked-list, interview-questions

I have some imminent interviews and want to sharpen my game before going into them. I'm running through some practice problems. This [LeetCode challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) is to add two numbers represented as linked lists.

If you can critique this solution quite harshly, as though you would in a full-fledged SWE interview, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm particularly concerned about memory usage and variable names.

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:         
        final_l = None
        curr_l = None
        remainder = 0
        while l1 or l2:
            digit = 0
            if l1:
                digit += l1.val
                l1 = l1.next    

            if l2: 
                digit += l2.val
                l2 = l2.next            

            if remainder != 0:    
                digit += remainder

            remainder = digit // 10
            digit = digit % 10 

            if final_l is None:
                final_l = ListNode(digit)
                curr_l = final_l
            else:
                curr_l.next = ListNode(digit)
                curr_l = curr_l.next            

        if remainder > 0:
            curr_l.next = ListNode(remainder)


        return final_l
```

Answer (score 4):

**A bit of scaffolding**

In order to test/review your code, I had to write a bit of additional code. In case it can be relevant to you or other reviewers, here it is:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        ret = other is not None and self.val == other.val and self.next == other.next
        # print(self, other, ret)
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, l):
        ret = ln = cls(l.pop(0))
        while l:
            e = l.pop(0)
            ln.next = cls(e)
            ln = ln.next
        return ret

    def to_list(self):
        l = [self.val]
        return l if self.next is None else l + self.next.to_list()

class Solution:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def ListNodeFromInt(n):
        return ListNode.from_list([int(d) for d in reversed(str(n))])

    @staticmethod
    def testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(n1, n2):
        l1 = Solution.ListNodeFromInt(n1)
        l2 = Solution.ListNodeFromInt(n2)
        expected_add = Solution.ListNodeFromInt(n1 + n2)
        add = Solution().addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)
        print(n1, n2, n1 + n2, expected_add.to_list(), add.to_list())
        assert expected_add == add


    @staticmethod
    def unitTests():
        # Edge cases
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(0, 0)
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(342, 0)
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(0, 342)
        # Same length
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(342, 465)
        # Different length
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(342, 46)
        # Return longer than input
        Solution.testAddTwoNumbersUsingNumbers(999, 999)

Solution.unitTests()
```

This is pretty poorly organised but it is quick and dirty.
Now starts the actual review

**Overall review**

Your code looks good. The API is a bit awkward but it is a limitation from the programming challenge platform.

A few details can be improved anyway.

**Remove non-required checks**

Instead of:

```
        if remainder != 0:    
            digit += remainder
```

You can write:

```
        digit += remainder
```

**Use builtins**

The builtin [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#divmod) is not the most famous but it is convenient for a pretty usual task: compute both the quotient and the remainder.

Instead of:

```
        remainder = digit // 10
        digit = digit % 10
```

You can write:

```
        remainder, digit = divmod(digit, 10)
```

**Different strategy**

Instead of having a function to perform all the steps in one go, you could split the problem: define a function computing the sum of the 2 list as an integer and a function to convert that number into a list. Adding values bigger than 9 may be what we are trying to avoid though...